# ASP.NET core 2.2 crashes because of too many open files in system

Tags: c#, linux, sockets, .net-core, cloud-foundry

Our application is running on a cloud foundry server and since a few weeks we get the following exception:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Too many open files in system --- System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Too many open files in system at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType) at System.Net.Sockets.DualSocketMultipleConnectAsync..ctor(SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ConnectAsync(SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType, SocketAsyncEventArgs e) at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

If I check in the container the sockets, there are a lot of socket-dumps and the number of them increases very fastly (see picture above)

My call in the container:

```
lsof | grep 'sock'
```

**UPDATE:**

Now I've found out, which part of the application causes this problem, but I have no idea why:

In order to call an external API from our client for our map layer I've created a proxy on our backend:

```
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMapLayerProxy(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var config = (app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IOptions<AppSettings>)) as IOptions<AppSettings>).Value.MapServer;
            if (IsMapLayerRequest(context, config))
            {
                var forwardedHost = context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Host"].ToArray().FirstOrDefault();
                if (forwardedHost == null)
                {
                    context.Request.Headers.Add("X-Forwarded-Host", context.Request.Host.ToString());
                }

                var builder = app.New(); // branch app to lose all middlewares and prevent infinity recursion
                builder.RunProxy(new ProxyOptions
                {
                    Scheme = config.Scheme,
                    Host = config.Host,
                });
                await builder.Build().Invoke(context);
            }
            else
            {
                await next.Invoke();
            }
        });

        return app;
    }

    private static bool IsMapLayerRequest(HttpContext httpContext, MapServerSettings config)
    {
        return Array.Exists(config.LayerPaths, path => httpContext.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith(path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
```

startup.cs:

```
app.UseMapLayerProxy();
```

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

I've changed the code of the proxy and now it works well. But I'm not sure, if this is the right way in order to implement a conditional reverse Proxy (depending on the request url). Are there maybe better ways?

```
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMapLayerProxy(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var config = (app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IOptions<AppSettings>)) as IOptions<AppSettings>).Value.MapServer;
        app.MapWhen(
            (httpContext) =>
            {   
                if (IsMapLayerRequest(httpContext, config)) {
                     httpContext.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic BASE64_PW");
                }

                return IsMapLayerRequest(httpContext, config);
            },
            builder => builder.RunProxy(new ProxyOptions
            {
                Scheme = config.Scheme,
                Host = config.Host,
            }));

        return app;
    }

    private static bool IsMapLayerRequest(HttpContext httpContext, MapServerSettings config)
    {
        return Array.Exists(config.LayerPaths, path => httpContext.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith(path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
```

Comment: Well, it must be a `out of resource` thing. What about the code using the http client, is the response also being cleaned up?

Comment: @FrankNielsen i've updated the code. Hope it helps?

Comment: Is it possible to switch off this `IsMapLayerRequest` thing or avoid that route - for testing? My guess is that breaking that chain could to missing socket cleanup.

Comment: @FrankNielsen yes, as in the update said, if i switch off the IsMapLayerRequest, it resolve the problem.

Comment: What is the idea of the `IsMapLayerRequest` and related code?

Comment: @FrankNielsen it checks if the path of the request is for the map layer, if yes it use the proxy.

Comment: I am guessing here. Since you are doing a `var builder = app.New();`, may all the services in the app.ServiceProvider must be disposed before the New. I guess that `var builder = app.New();` is creating a new service scope.

Comment: @FrankNielsen how do you the solution now?

Comment: Looks correct, and much simpler :)

Comment: @FrankNielsen but now a little problem: how can I conditionally set a httpheader?

Comment: Where do you get `RunProxy` and `ProxyOptions` from? it is not part of AspNetCore v2.0+

Comment: @FrankNielsen yes, it is a part of that. I've now edited my code again and added an "If-clause" to the "MapWhen-clause" In order to set the Authorization httpheader (see my last update). It works on the test server, if I deploy it. But on my local machine after starting my sever (runngin kestrel too), the very fist call to the remote server get a 403. Every call after that works fine.

Comment: OKay, seems you have got further. If you still got problems with 403 on first page - create a new SO.

Comment: @FrankNielsen I hope you have some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60211549/net-core-setting-manually-authorization-header-using-reverse-proxy-causes-401